# If BkGd process is ready to receive Keys, Client process sends keys to BkGd process which puts them in KeyBoard buffer

Tags: windows, visual-c++, ipc

Note: Each key = 16 bits: output from VkKeyScan or UniCode

While this is only one way IPC (from Client to BkGd), before sending Keys for the Keyboard buffer Client MUST ask "OK to send?" and BkGd MUST respond "Ready to Receive".

When this was developed as a TSR in ASM in 1984, the Client read the head and tail in BkGd's memory to determine if BkGd was ready to receive and then wrote the keys in BkGd's memory (similar to WriteProcessMemory).

My pseudo code so far:
1. Client: FindWindow of BkGd:
2. Client: Register with BkGd, effectively asking "OK to Send?"
3. BkGd: "OK, ready to Recieve"
4. Client: Send all of the keys to BkGd
5. BkGd: Puts keys in Keyboard buffer
6. BkGd: When finished processing Client's Keys, sends Client OK, ready to Receive

While it's just Client->BkGd->Keyboard buffer, please help us filter thru the MANY ways this could be done to the simplest and most reliable way it should be done. :-)

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, this has become much simpler.

Since Keys are ONLY for the Process that the Client just started, and
if a previous process aborted, any remaining Keys are no longer needed...

Client just:
1. HWND hWnd = FindWindow(TEXT("BkGd"), 0);
2. Defines the COPYDATASTRUCT
3. SendMessage WM_COPYDATA

BkGd/Server
1. receives WM_COPYDATA (0x004A) message containing the Keys
2. puts (SendInput) the Keys in Keyboard buffer